# querying for subjects or predicates by regex

Tags: rdf, sparql

Given this RDF:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [<!ENTITY rdf 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>
<!ENTITY rdfs 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#'>
<!ENTITY xsd 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'>]>

<rdf:RDF xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" 
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="Fadi" xml:startTime="00:01:38" xml:endTime="00:01:39">
    <ns0:eat xmlns:ns0="http://example.org/">Apple</ns0:eat>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

when I execute this SPARQL query

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o . 
  FILTER (regex(?o, 'Apple','i'))
}
```

I get the subject and predicate:

```
s: http://example.org/Fadi , p: http://example.org/eat .
```

but when I execute

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER (regex(?s, 'Fadi','i'))
}
```

or

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER (regex(?s, 'http://example.org/Fadi','i'))
}
```

I get nothing. How can i query for subject or predicate?
How can I query about `startTime` and `endTime`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

?s is a URI and regex works on strings.  Use the **str** function to get a string:

```
FILTER (regex(str(?s), 'Fadi','i'))
```

Answer (score 12):

[`REGEX`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-regex) is for querying text values, not for matching against resource IRIs.  You could use the [`str`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-str) function to get the IRI of a resource, so your filter would look like

```
FILTER (regex( str( ?s ), 'http://example.org/Fadi','i'))
```

but that's *really* not what you want to do here.  Since you are looking to retrieve triples of the form

```
<http://example.org/Fadi> ?p ?o
```

ask for them with a query like this:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  <http://example.org/Fadi> ?p ?o .
}
```

You can define prefixes in SPARQL queries, too, so if you're using a bunch of terms from one namespace, you can save some typing by, e.g.,

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
SELECT * 
WHERE {
 ex:Fadi ?p ?o .
}
```

However, there's still another problem with your example.  Your RDF document doesn't have any XML base, the IRI for `Fadi` in `<rdf:Description rdf:about="Fadi" ...` is unpredictable.  A SPARQL engine might resolve it against a filename, creating, for instance `/home/user/input.rdf/Fadi`.  Either specify an XML base, or use full IRIs for the `rdf:about` property.  Assuming we add `xml:base="http://www.example.org/"` to the `rdf:RDF` element, we can run those queries using [Jena ARQ](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/) command line tools, we get output containing the triples we expect, but also some messages about those `startTime` and `endTime` attributes:

```
$ arq --data fadi.rdf --query fadi.sparql 
12:13:21 WARN  riot                 :: {W118} XML attribute: xml:startTime is not known and is being discarded.
12:13:21 WARN  riot                 :: {W118} XML attribute: xml:endTime is not known and is being discarded.
----------------------------------------------------
| s                             | p      | o       |
====================================================
| <http://www.example.org/Fadi> | ex:eat | "Apple" |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Those property values need to specified by elements within the `rdf:Description` element.  I don't think that `xml:startTime` and `xml:endTime` are meaningful properties;  whatever start time and end time mean here, they should probably be specified by different properties, but that's a modeling issue, not a syntax issue.  At any rate, we can adjust the input file accordingly to get (with the `xml:base` and `xml:(start|end)Time` elements):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [<!ENTITY rdf 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>
<!ENTITY rdfs 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#'>
<!ENTITY xsd 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'>]>

<rdf:RDF xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" 
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xml:base="http://www.example.org/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="Fadi">
    <ns0:eat xmlns:ns0="http://example.org/">Apple</ns0:eat>
    <xml:startTime>00:01:38</xml:startTime>
    <xml:endTime>00:01:39</xml:endTime>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Now when we run the query, we get

```
$ /usr/local/lib/apache-jena-2.10.0/bin/arq --data fadi.rdf --query fadi.sparql 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| s                             | p                                               | o          |
================================================================================================
| <http://www.example.org/Fadi> | <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespaceendTime>   | "00:01:39" |
| <http://www.example.org/Fadi> | <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespacestartTime> | "00:01:38" |
| <http://www.example.org/Fadi> | ex:eat                                          | "Apple"    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

which seems like what you wanted.  More specific queries, e.g., for the Fadi's start and end times, are easy to construct too.  Using the `startTime` and `endTime` properties as they appear so far (even though they should be refactored into a different namespace later), we have:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.org/>
PREFIX xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ex:Fadi xml:startTime ?start ;
          xml:endTime ?end .
}
```

which produces

```
$ /usr/local/lib/apache-jena-2.10.0/bin/arq --data fadi.rdf --query fadi.sparql 
---------------------------
| start      | end        |
===========================
| "00:01:38" | "00:01:39" |
---------------------------
```

Comment: thank you :D
yes this is what i need.
but still i need to know how to get just the startTime and EndTime with Query.  i have to use startTime with movie.

thank you again.. Grateful to you.
@Joshua Taylor

Comment: iam using c# dotnetrdf
when i tried to load the rdf file. it gaves me:
Unable to Parse this RDF/XML since System.Xml was unable to parse the document, see Inner Exception for details

can u help me? @Joshua Taylor

Comment: @HasanSarraj That sounds like a different question.  I don't have experience with C#, but you might get some answers if you post a separate question on this site.

Comment: SELECT * WHERE { { ?s ?p ?o .FILTER (regex( str( ?s ), 'http://example.org/Fadi','i')) } UNION { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } } }

i get all answer not just with subject = Fadi.  what is the problem?

Comment: @HasanSarraj That's really a separate question.  I expect that the FILTER only applies to the left pattern in the UNION, and that the right pattern in the UNION which includes `?s ?p ?o` grabs everything.

Comment: i don't know what to do, this is another query:
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/> SELECT * WHERE { { ex:fadi ?p ?o } UNION { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } } }

same thing all answers :/

Comment: That second query is saying retrieving both **all the triples with subject ex:fadi$$ and **all the triples**.  That's going to give you **all the triples**.

Comment: ok please tell me how just to get triples with subject = fadi when i have the triples in graph g

Comment: @HasanSarraj That would be much better posed as a separate question.  That way people can find the it as a complete question and answer, and not have to crawl through comments (which can be deleted!).

Comment: i did: the new question: dotnetrdf Graph Sparql query.

Comment: @jousha Taylor..
how can i get The Time with query for object? like this:
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . FILTER (regex(?o, '" + q + "','i')) }
can you edit the answer to help?

Comment: @HasanSarraj The answer above _does_ show the start time and end times (in spite of being in the XML namespace).  If you have another question, you should post it as a separate question.

Comment: its the same question.. i need to get startTime and endTime but with query about object not with query about subject.

Comment: i asked another question.. it's:
sparql query about object to find another object